# Setting Up Firebase For Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I been settling up the project on Firebase. The app has been set up for iOS and Android. It works fine for Flutter Run but it doesn't connect to Firebase

The code in Main.dart is as followed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';import 'package:footballcrazyquiz/routes.dart';import 'package:footballcrazyquiz/theme.dart';import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';import 'package:provider/provider.dart';import 'package:footballcrazyquiz/shared/shared.dart';import 'package:footballcrazyquiz/services/services.dart';
```

```
void main() {WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();runApp(const App());}
```

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {const App({super.key});
```

```
@overrideState<App> createState() => _AppState();}class _AppState extends State<App> {final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
```

```
@overrideWidget build(BuildContext context) {return FutureBuilder(// Initialize FlutterFire:future: _initialization,builder: (context, snapshot) {// Check for errorsif (snapshot.hasError) {
```

```
    }

    // Once complete, show your application
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
     return StreamProvider(
        create: (_) => FirestoreService().streamReport(),
        catchError: (_, err) => Report(),
        initialData: Report(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
          routes: appRoutes,
          theme: appTheme
        ),
      );
    }

    // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
    return const MaterialApp(home: LoadingScreen());
  },
);
```

```
}}
```

I'm also not able to generate Android Signing In report in terminal, which I need for SHA 1. Exception is in Android/app/build.gradle line 28 and that's as followed

```
def localProperties = new Properties()def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->localProperties.load(reader)}}
```

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')if (flutterRoot == null) {throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")}
```

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')if (flutterVersionCode == null) {flutterVersionCode = '1'}
```

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')if (flutterVersionName == null) {flutterVersionName = '1.0'}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

```
android {compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersionndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "io.eddiegamble.footballcrazyquiz"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 31.0.1
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multidex true
    
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

```
}
```

```
flutter {source '../..'}
```

```
dependencies {implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do you import firebase_options.dart into the project? DefaultFirebaseOptions is the only problem I have got so far.

Comment: firebase_options.dart is automatically generated once you configure your project with firebase. Check out these instructions https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web

Comment: Thank You Hunter Books. Been getting on well with it right up to flutter fire configure bit on step 2. Getting command not found. Please note: I was getting this   export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin when installing Flutterfire, is that stopping flutter fire configure from working? P.s. I already have a project in Firebase which is the one I'm trying to use.

Comment: You installed the firebase CLI?

Comment: I think I have done it right. Says I'm login to Firebase and can see a list of the projects

Comment: I done step 2- configure your apps to use in Firebase. However on step 3, when i do flutter pub add firebase_core, I can't run flutterfire configure and says the command can not be found. Can only add it when I do export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin". Run the app and although it loads, Firebase still isn't connected to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with that. Definitely sounds off to me

Comment: I think so, going to put in another question with the up to date code in main.dart and hope someone can work it out